# How to extract date from the filename using Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, date

I am trying to extract the date from this filename format:

```
"output_AU1001-BY.20160502.csv"
```

I thought maybe I can do it with `re.findall()` but could not do it.

Comment: With the information given, it's hard to tell what your specific problem is.  Please show the code you tried, together with the expected and actual output.

Comment: Elaborate on the filename format. Which parts are fixed, which parts are variable, and by what rules do they vary?

Comment: `re.search(r'\d{8}', filename).group()`?

Comment: Hi all, I do not know why you gave me negative points, I appreciate the input and all of the parts are fixed expect the date, I am trying to extract the date out of the filename. I did not have specific code for re.findall() but my online search suggested me that I can use that function. Dot_py's answer was efficient and worked for me.

Comment: @Pythoner1234 when you post a question: (1) explain in a easy way what you're trying to achieve, aka posting the expected input/output (2) provide a reproducible example, (3) provide the code you've produced to show us what you already tried. The 3rd point is the most important! Stackoverflow isn't a "free coding" service, thus showing us your code is a way to demonstrate some effort from your part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
import re

d = 'output_AU1001-BY.20160502.csv'
d = re.sub('output_[A-Z]+[0-9]+-BY[.]([0-9]+)[.]csv$', r'\1', d)
print d
```

Assumptions:

- `output_` is constant for all file names
- `AU` is variable, but will always be ALL CAPS
- `-BY.` is constant for all file names
- `20160502` is variable, but will always be all digits
- `.csv` is constant for all file names

Answer (score 5):

**Example without regex**

**Code**:

```
s = 'output_AU1001-BY.20160502.csv'
date = s.split(".")[1]
print date
```

**Output**:

```
>>> 20160502
```